# Unsold iPhones & Battery Life

Tags: iphone, battery, apple-store

There is a lot unsold [iPhones 4s](http://store.apple.com/us/buy-iphone/iphone4s) on the Apple Store.
According to the ["About iPhone Batteries"](http://www.apple.com/batteries/iphone.html), iPhone's battery should be regularly charged. But in case that the battery is not charge after the iPhone has been packed in 2011-2012, what will be the condition of those batteries? After all this time for several years on the stock.

Comment: I don't know whether Apple sells "old" phones or whether they simply kept on producing the older model into 2013. However, I can point you to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery#Battery_life) that has some things to say about the effects of storage on Li-ion batteries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the batteries are maintained since [Lithium-ion polymer batteries need to be used and recharged regularly](https://www.apple.com/batteries/). There will definitely be some reduction in capacity as time passes, regardless of whether the batteries are regularly used/charged or not.

From [Battery University - Is Lithium-ion the Ideal Battery?](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/is_lithium_ion_the_ideal_battery) (emphasis mine):

> Aging is a concern with most lithium-ion batteries and many manufacturers remain silent about this issue. *Some capacity deterioration is noticeable after one year, whether the battery is in use or not.* The battery frequently fails after two or three years. It should be noted that other chemistries also have age-related degenerative effects. This is especially true for nickel-metal-hydride if exposed to high ambient temperatures. At the same time, lithium-ion packs are known to have served for five years in some applications.
>
> *Manufacturers are constantly improving lithium-ion. New and enhanced chemical combinations are introduced every six months or so. With such rapid progress, it is difficult to assess how well the revised battery will age.*

References:
[Apple - Lithium-ion Batteries](https://www.apple.com/batteries/)
[Battery University](http://batteryuniversity.com/)